# Как получить свойство файла "описание"?

Tags: c++, qt

У каждого (исполняемого) файла можно помимо имени просмотреть описание, (в классе `QFileInfo` не нашла такого свойства файла), есть ли оно, и где? (Можно и не средствами qt, если нет выбора)

Comment: Что имеется в виду под "описанием"?

Comment: @kff Правой кнопкой на файле - свойства - описание (не размер-разрешение и т.д. а именно текстовое поле описание). У меня задача именно по описанию файла искать нужный )

Comment: У меня нет такого... Какая ОС?

Comment: Windows 10, да в любой винде оно есть."Description" по английски )

Comment: В любой? У меня нет. Ткните меня носом: http://funkyimg.com/i/26H5B.png

Comment: На исполняемых файлах смотрите (.exe), поправила вопрос :)

Comment: Скорее всего, это не кросс-платформенная опция файла, поэтому в qt ее и нет.

Comment: А! Нашёл. Подумаю...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Наличие описания файла не является кроссплатформенным, поэтому *Qt* такой функциональности не предоставляет. Как верно заметил @ВладимирМартьянов, Вам нужно воспользоваться *WinAPI*, а именно, функцией [`GetFileVersionInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms647003%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Но как это всегда бывает в *WinAPI*, она тащит за собой кучу других функций, тонны проверок и в итоге получается следующий довольно непростой листинг:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <Strsafe.h>

#include <cstdio>

#pragma pack(push,1)
struct Translation
{
    WORD language;
    WORD codePage;
};
#pragma pack(pop)

int main()
{
    const wchar_t *const fileName = L"c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Office\\Adobe Reader\\Reader\\AcroRd32.exe";

    // Получаем размер информации о файле.
    const DWORD infoSize = GetFileVersionInfoSizeW(fileName, NULL);
    if (infoSize > 0)
    {
        BYTE info[infoSize];  // Здесь будет информация.
        // Получаем информацию.
        if (GetFileVersionInfoW(fileName, 0, infoSize, info))
        {
            const Translation* translation;  // Указатель на начало массива языковых блоков.
            UINT translationSize;            // Число языковых блоков.
            // Получаем массив языковых блоков и их число.
            if (VerQueryValueW(info, L"\\VarFileInfo\\Translation", (LPVOID*)&translation, &translationSize))
            {
                // Цикл по всем языковым блокам.
                for (int i = 0; i < translationSize / sizeof(Translation); ++i)
                {
                    const size_t BUFFER_LEN = 64;
                    WCHAR subBlockName[BUFFER_LEN];  // Буфер для имени языкового блока.
                    // Формируем имя языкового блока.
                    HRESULT hResult = StringCchPrintfW(subBlockName,
                                                       BUFFER_LEN,
                                                       L"\\StringFileInfo\\%04x%04x\\FileDescription",
                                                       translation[i].language,
                                                       translation[i].codePage);
                    if (SUCCEEDED(hResult))
                    {
                        LPBYTE value;  // Указатель на нужную нам строку.
                        UINT len;      // Длина строки.
                        // Получаем языковой блок.
                        if (VerQueryValueW(info, subBlockName, (LPVOID*)&value, &len))
                        {
                            printf("\"%ls=\"%ls\"\n", subBlockName, value);
                        }
                        else {
                            printf("VerQueryValue error: %d.\n", GetLastError());
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        printf("StringCchPrintf error: %d.\n", hResult);
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                printf("VerQueryValue error: %d.\n", GetLastError());
            }
        }
        else {
            printf("GetFileVersionInfo error: %d.\n", GetLastError());
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("GetFileVersionInfoSize error: %d.\n", GetLastError());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

P.S. В *MinGW* нужно прилинковать `libversion.a`, в `MSVC` - `version.lib`.

Comment: Спасибо большое за такой развернутый ответ!

Comment: А у вас компилируется строчка BYTE info[infoSize]? у меня выдает ошибку компиляции, пришлось заменить на std::vector <BYTE> info(infoSize);

Comment: @Mira Компилируется. Это компилировалось в *GCC5*, он более лоялен к автоматическим переменным типа массив с длиной, неизвестной на стадии компиляции. У *MSVC* с этим всегда были проблемы. Вроде как в *MSVC 2015* это починили, но я не уверен. Если не компилируется, можно либо `vector`, как Вы предложили, либо размещать массив в динамической памяти.

Comment: @kiff - библиотека которую необходимо подключить -не mincore.lib а version.lib . В документации к сожалению непростительная ошибка, поправьте пожалуйста ответ :) чтоб не искать функции там где их нет.

Comment: @Mira Спасибо. Поправил. Сам в MSVC не проверял - поверил MSDN. :-(

Answer (score 2):

Судя по всему, вам нужна функция GetFileVersionInfo из WinAPI.

Comment: Похоже оно! сейчас буду пробовать.